# When will Ethel be able to rejoin the party?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

During Chapter 3 I got a prompt saying if I progressed the main story I would be unable to include Ethel in my party. How long will Ethel be excluded from the party if I advance the main plot? Will I eventually be able to re-add her?

[image: "once you enter the office, you'll be unable to include Ethel in the party"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Will I eventually be able to re-add her?

Yes.

> How long will Ethel be excluded from the party if I advance the main plot?

Until chapter 6. Worth noting however that she doesn't rejoin automatically.

## Making Ethel rejoin

(Chapter 6 spoilers ahead. I've tried to be as vague as possible)

> You'll need to unlock the Seraph class, and level up both it and Flash Fencer to level 10. The pre-requisites to unlock Seraph are story-related, but the unlock mission itself is still optional.
>  After that, you'll want to go to the lab on the back of the colony where you started the Seraph unlock mission. You'll be given a choice, with one of the options making Ethel rejoin. If you choose the "wrong" option, you'll still be able to choose the "right" one.

Comment: It’s worth noting that this cannot be done until chapter 6, and doesn’t happen automatically; it requires a side quest

Comment: What do you need to do to get Ethel to rejoin the party?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I have rewriten the answer, adding details